# How do you solve $y''+4y=0$ using $='$ and $(d/d)=''$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

I asked a similar question not too long ago, however after I posted it, I realized I accidentally put 4x and not 4y, so I apologize for the previous post. I am working on ODE and can't figure out how to do it without complex roots. Supposedly, I am to solve as above, where =∫d/.However, when I set up the equation, I am stumped on how to solve. I would appreciate the help! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. You have the substitution suggested. Try plugging it into the original ODE. You'll find that you get a first-order ODE solving for $p(y)$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Here it is another possible approach:
\begin{align*}
y'' + 4y = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow y''y' + 4yy' = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (2y''y') + 4(2yy') = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (y')^{2} + 4y^{2} = k
\end{align*}
where $k\geq 0$.

Can you take it from here?